# @EnableJpaRepositories will not work with JPA Data repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, datasource

I'm trying to run Spring Boot with two data sources. So far so good, but the problem occurred when I tried to use Spring JPA Data. SimpleJPARepository do not reflect the transaction manager set by

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "cz.data.external",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "externalEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "externalTransactionManager")
```

It seems it still uses the one marked as primary. 
The javadoc says

> transactionManagerRef - Configures the name of the {@link PlatformTransactionManager} bean definition to be used to create repositories    discovered through this annotation.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not supported by Data JPA? To change the transaction manager.

Comment: Check this configuration https://gist.github.com/eddumelendez/976c30a5bc64ffcd5d74

Comment: We've already discovered the issue in an answer. It's not a configuration issue but a bug in Spring 4.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Spring 4.1.4 by accident? It seems you're running into [this regression](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-12577). We recommend to use Spring 4.1.3 (by explicitly setting the `spring.version` property in case of a Boot project) until 4.1.5 is released.

Comment: This is the issue many thanks. Just note spring.version property directly in my pom was not working so I passed it via -Dspring.version=4.1.3.RELEASE which worked. Many Thanks Oliver